# Primefaces p:focus not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need focus specify Id(i.e commandbutton,selectonemenu and text) is not working.I try this below code:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
<p:inputText id="name"/>
<p:inputText id="Age"/>
   <p:selectOneRadio id="Gender" value="#{employee.gender}" layout="custom">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="Male" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="Female" />

        </p:selectOneRadio>
<p:commandButton  id="clear" value="Press" action="{employee.saveAction}">
<p:focus for="Gender"/>
</p:commandButton>

<p:commandButton id="clear" value="clear"/>
</h:form>
```

I try focus radio button or id="clear" commandbutton or text button is not focus.

**Note: I tried `context="specifyid"` replace for it also not working.**

Comment: Does it work for 'Age' ? I think I read about focus not working for selects (not sure though, but searching the internet might yield something)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you put `<p:focus>` inside `<p:commandButton>`. Maybe this is causing problems. According to the [docs](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/focus.xhtml) you can put the tag direct into a `<h:form>` and set focus on your `<p:selectOneRadio>`:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
  <p:focus for="Gender" />
  <p:inputText id="name" />
  <p:inputText id="Age" />
  <p:selectOneRadio id="Gender" value="#{employee.gender}" layout="custom">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="Male" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="Female" />
  </p:selectOneRadio>
  <p:commandButton id="clear" value="Press" action="{employee.saveAction}" />
  <p:commandButton id="clear" value="clear" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: When press commandbutton focus  specify id becuase I use more than one command button and many focus. So I click commandbutton to focus specify ID

Comment: Why don't you use JavaScript instead? `onclick="document.getElementById("Gender").focus();"`

Comment: It focus but it use  page to has to refersh